# Component failure in say LTSPICE

Tags: failure, emulator

Does anyone know through direct experience if LTSPICE or other major circuit emulators actually report component failures in some way. If I were to plug in say over voltage values to known components in even simple circuits. Or does it just freeze up.

Answer (score 3):

Components in spice-based simulators are "ideal" and don't fail. The simulator won't freeze up for that reason.

However, you can easily write expressions for component parameters that you want to monitor, such as device power dissipation, and plot them along with voltages and currents to see whether they exceed any limits.

Comment: +1 Yup, pity though. It would also be nice if they showed thermal colors so you could see at a glance what needs improved.

Comment: @Trevor: Maybe as a non-default option. The rest of us who simulate complex circuits well within the capabilities of the components would not want our simulations slowed down by such a frill. That said, you can use resistors and capacitors to simulate key thermal paths in your system, and use comparators to tell you whether a limit has been exceeded anywhere in a path.

Comment: Yes I was thinking both of those too.

Comment: Though thinking again, the effects of self-heating can significantly impact the simulation, so having it in would be beneficial.

Comment: @Trevor: In that case, use a custom device model that explicitly includes such effects. It isn't difficult.

Comment: Some SPICE's will emit a warning if a voltage goes out of bounds so far that it's affecting the numerical precision of the output. Like "Device D1 is melting with current of 131.21203e15 A." (IIRC it's SPICE3 that actually used the word "melting" in this error message)

Comment: @DaveTweed At first glance, I completely agreed with your statement. But then I thought about the fact that so far as my experience goes, Spice itself does runs at a single temperature. You can step through different temps, but there's an internal applied variable that is present. Wrapping a BJT into a .SUBCKT would seem to do what you say, with added components [perhaps behavioral even], but as you add Spice components they use internal functions in Spice (such as Isat variation over temp.) You might have to do all of it with behaviorals? Now I think I'd like to see this done, once or twice.

Comment: @jonk: Running a simulation at a particular temperature is intended for chip-level simulation, where the assumption that the whole chip is at the same temperature makes sense. However, it does not take into account any self-heating effects (especially of individual components), which is what Trevor is asking about, and must be modeled explicitly.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes, I understood that much. I guess I was thinking instead about designing a .SUBCKT that would, for example, simulate self-heating (with added heat flow constants?) of a part. I'm trying to imagine how to do that for something even as simple as a Q in Spice, creating a .SUBCKT instead of using Q. One could not use a Q part within the .SUBCKT because that would call subroutines which access Spice variables affecting formulas using device parameters. Which makes this an interesting exercise to me. I'm not sure how I'd approach doing a credible job of it. Sounds like hard work to me.

Comment: @jonk: You probably know a lot more about the internal functions and variables of spice than I do, so I can't comment on that. I'm just saying that conceptually, it isn't difficult to use electrical components to model thermal characteristics. Voltage represents temperature, and current represents heat (power) flow. A behavioral current source can be defined as the product of voltage and current across, say, a resistor. capacitors can represent thermal capacities and resistors can represent thermal resistances.

Comment: A custom device can have an extra terminal that represents its case temperature, to which you connect additional components that represent heat sinks, etc. (A voltage source represents ambient temperature at the end of the thermal path.) Then, you can make the resistance itself a function of its own case temperature -- but even if you don't, you can still monitor that temperature and see whether it ever rises high enough to indicate that the resistor has "burned out", which is what the OP was asking about.