# Modelling catastrophic component failure

Tags: components, spice, modeling, failure

For most of the time in circuit simulation, the component models used are ideal and don't feature fail-states e.g. [this answer here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/339510/component-failure-in-say-ltspice).

Have there been any projects that have attempted to model what a circuit might do in the case of catastrophic failure? For example, if a component explodes/melts?

I mainly ask because I find the idea humorous, but there are obviously real use-cases. If a component can be predicted to fail in a certain way then the effect on the rest of the circuit can be predicted as well. A fuse is an obvious case of this, but I am thinking more where the component is not designed to fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd do something like that, you'd have to calculate, automatically, the voltages and currents through the circuit, then add their own *physical* limitations, such as thermal resistance, air flow, etc. Now imagine you have a 1000 elements schematic. The matrix will be "yuge" and, in most of the cases, to avoid waiting for disk writes, you'd make use of the `.save` command, to selectively save only the desired components. If you want power dissipation (automatically needed for any thermal blow-up simulator), that command becomes useless. Now go a bit further and try to imagine those 1000 elements being, all inside a chip -- you'd have to calculate and save everything. I can already hear future generations of CPUs hiding from the shelves.

All this can be avoided by some extra attention that the user has to pay when simulating. I think it's not only fair, but a comodity (years ago they did simulations on paper, and they worked...), and wanting more and more comodity can lead to down-right lazyness. Wait until you see how whole schematics blow up because "designers" will complain that the colour of their device was orange, not purple, and they couldn't have known that the element would blow up based on the colour... not to mention the elaborate excuses, because this is where you'd be getting at -- motivation of formulating excuses, instead of developing a bit of extra attention. Well, it sounds more like a rant, and I suppose there is some of that, inside there, but it's also what I believe: features like these might seem helpful, but if they are , it's only for a (very) short term, the long term tends to bury them in negative outcomes.

Comment: 1000="yuge" ... right now I am simulating 939390 elements => ca 200 ms / timestep in CPU time.

Comment: @HKOB I take it they're all RLC, or close? I doubt they're nonlinear elements, maybe not even 1% of them, but, of course, I could be wrong.

Comment: 28.1k MOSFETs is ~3%, so you are quite close ;) but this is only 1 cpu, and no parasitic reduction, so i am still some way away from a computational wall (for my accuracy requirements).

Comment: @HKOB Could I also dare guess this is no switching application? :-) (not mainly, maybe some controls, here and there)

Comment: It's a 14+2 bit ADC, so plenty of analog and digital signals. But 200 ms/timestep was with low accuracy to get initial operating point. Now at higher accuracy I get one step every 2.7 seconds.

Comment: You haven't really answered the question, just offered an alternative. I also disagree with better tools making lazy engineers, but that is obviously up for debate! Thank you for your interesting perspective though :)

Comment: @loudnoises Eh, what can I say, somedays you feel like the only possible answer is a good rant. The only thing left is syncronizing, apparently missed it. :-)